# How do I connect my iMac to a Windows SMB share drive

Tags: network, smb

I work in an organization that runs a Windows network of 1000s of computers with Windows 7 installed. We have lots of SMB share drives that store information. My job is a new role for a graphic design area and I've been setup with an iMac.

**Now the problem:** This is the only iMac in the organization and I'm not familiar with share drives. I've been told that I've had my "credentials" set up and should be able to connect to an SMB share drive that contains all our fonts, images, and videos.

**How do I connect my iMac to this Windows SMB share drive?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This answer assumes a few things:

- your iMac is already connected to the network (most likely via ethernet)
- that your credentials are all setup (based on your question, they are)
- that you’ve been given the host address for the share drive

To connect to the share drive, you should only have to:

1. Make sure the Finder is active
2. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (or, in the top menubar, click on Go and select the **Connect to Server…** option)
3. A *Connect to Server* window will appear with a Server Address field
4. In this field enter the host address (it should start with **smb://**)
5. Click on the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button
6. You should now be connected and able to access all the files via the Finder

**Note:** - If you’re not already connected to the network, or you require different credentials for this share drive, then after Step 5 you may be prompted to enter your username and password.

**[EDIT]**

If you do have to enter your username and password, it's likely you will need to enter the username in the form of "DOMAIN\username" where "DOMAIN" is the name of your Active Directory domain. If you're unsure of this, your IT helpdesk should be able to tell you.

Answer (score 8):

Your IT department shouldn't have just abandoned you at this point. They should have worked through it with you.

We can't really answer this without knowing more detail of the network setup there, but the basic premise would be to start from
Finder > Go > Connect to Server...
simply type `smb://[address you should have already been given]` & hit Enter.

Corporate networking is really beyond the scope of Ask Different & ought to be handled by your own IT team.

Comment: Note that you can use the IP address of the server or the name of the server. When it asks for your username and password you will likely need to enter the username in the form of "DOMAIN\username" where "DOMAIN" is the name of your Active Directory domain. Failing to qualify the username like that might lead to the login failing.

Comment: That's typical of Windows only IT departments.  Don't want to deal with the Mac.

Comment: @Harper Exactly. I come across this all the time. I often think they're a little _scared_ of Macs! LOL In any case, Tetsujin is 100% correct - they really shouldn't have abandoned the OP. You would think that it being the first Mac in the organisation they'd be a bit more keen to learn about it. Odds are it won't be the last Mac now! :)

Comment: @SteveChambers Good point! I totally forgot to mention that in my answer, although the OP seems to have sorted it. :)